# Macro Workbook is getting closed automatically in the middle of execution

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which will read file data from the defined path and copies the data to my Macro workbook's sheet. When I am running the code line by line, it is working perfectly fine. But when I run the entire code, it is getting closed automatically without my permission. Below is my previous code.

```
Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
'Open File and Copy Data
Set thatWB1 = Workbooks.Open(TimFilePath)
TFPLR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
TFPLC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
TFPLCLTR = Split(Cells(1, TFPLC).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
'MsgBox TFPLCLTR
Range("A2:" & TFPLCLTR & TFPLR).Select
Selection.Copy

'Paste Selected Data in Time Ranges Sheet
'thisWB.Activate
thisWB.Sheets(TimSheet).Activate
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
     ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Close the File
thatWB1.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

After I made the below updates, the workbook is still closing.

```
Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
'Open Time Range File and Copy Data
Set thatWB1 = Workbooks.Open(TimFilePath)
TFPLR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
TFPLC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
TFPLCLTR = Split(Cells(1, TFPLC).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
'MsgBox TFPLCLTR
Range("A2:" & TFPLCLTR & TFPLR).Copy
'Selection.Copy

'Paste Selected Data in Time Ranges Sheet
thisWB.Sheets(TimSheet).Activate
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
     ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
thisWB.Sheets(TimSheet).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Close the Time ranges File
thatWB1.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: you should not rely on `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook`.  And why do you open Workbook `TimFilePath` a 2nd time?

Comment: I tried Workbooks(TimeFilePath).Close. But it is also closing the Macro workbook. So, I tried Opening and closing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to solve this is by declaring a variable to fully control the open workbook in the same way you have for thisWB, eg:

```
Dim thatWB As Workbook

Set thatWB = Workbooks.Open(TimFilePath)
'do the work
thatWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: Hi - I did that. But now I am getting Runtime error '91' Object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: Forgot the `Set` command `Set thatWB = Workbooks.Open(TimFilePath)`

Comment: Whoops - thanks Darren, edited the answer to include this

Comment: Thanks both. It fixed the issue. :)

Comment: Hi Joerg - It worked yesterday. But today when I was running the code, it is getting closed again. My code opens 9 files and copies the data and then closes them. But the Macro workbook shouldn't get closed. Any thoughts here?

Comment: Hi @DarrenBartrup-Cook - It worked yesterday. But today, when I was running the code, it got closed again. My code opens 9 files and copies the data and then closes them. But the Macro workbook shouldn't get closed. Any thoughts here?

Comment: If you're closing the Activeworkbook then it's probably that line doing it. As FunThomas said you shouldn't trust that the Activebook will always be correct - the user could change it while the code is running.

Comment: Yeah @DarrenBartrup-Cook. But I removed that and using workbook variable to close. Still it is closing.

Comment: Could you edit your original question & add the updated code below your first block of code please.

Comment: Yes @DarrenBartrup-Cook. I've pasted the updated code

Comment: The only file your code closes is the one that `TimFilePath` points to.  Sorry, no idea why it's closing `ThisWorkbook`.  Does it do the same if you step through the code using F8?  If it does - which line causes the file to close?

Comment: No @DarrenBartrup-Cook. When I run it step by step, it is working properly. When I run the entire code, that's where I am getting error.

Comment: And there's no other code involved - just the procedure name and `End Sub`?  I've tried the code you posted - and it's working for me.  Do the files being opened contain code?  Maybe they execute and close the file?  This link will show how to disable the VBA in the file being opened: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.AutomationSecurity

Comment: There is some code which will do the same operation for 8 more files. The code is same but the variables are different. There is no code lied in the File which is being opened.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work without relying on `Active` anything.

```
Option Explicit 'This line is REALLY important.
'It forces you to declare each variable.
'Tools ~ Options ~ Editor. Tick 'Require Variable Declaration' to
'add it to each new module you create.

Public Sub Test()

    'Set references to required files.
    Dim TimFilePath As String
    TimFilePath = "C:/Somepath/MyFile.xlsx"
    
    Dim thatWB As Workbook
    Set thatWB = Workbooks.Open(TimFilePath)
    
    Dim thatWS As Worksheet
    Set thatWS = thatWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook 'Workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Set thisWS = thisWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Work on the files without selecting them.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = thatWS.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    If LastRow = 0 Then LastRow = 1
    
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    LastColumn = thatWS.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    If LastColumn = 0 Then LastColumn = 1
    
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Set LastCell = thatWS.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)

    thatWS.Range("A2", LastCell).Copy
    thisWS.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    thatWB.Close False

End Sub
```